# How to change mem parameter in kernel boot parameters fedora 25?

Tags: linux, boot, memory, performance, fedora

I have a problem with my HP ProBook 4540s like [this](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Desktop-Boot-and-Lockup/Performance-degrades-in-Probook-4540s-after-memory-upgrade/td-p/2268503)
When I upgrade my laptop ram from 4 to 12G it stop booting.I try to install fresh windows or fedora but it cannot boot.

fortunately some one found a workaround for this problem mentioned [here](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Desktop-Boot-and-Lockup/Performance-degrades-in-Probook-4540s-after-memory-upgrade/m-p/3919972#M27464)
The solution was to deduce small amount of memory using EasyBCD program or similars,so I tried it on windows 8.1 using EasyBCD and it works 100%, but when I migrate from windows to fedora 25 the problem rise again.In the solution mentioned before the user said

> Under Linux, set "mem=17G" in kernel boot parameters (effectively deduces 256 MB).

this is my question how to achieve this in fedora 25 and I am totally fresh fedora user?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same laptop 4540s, installed 16GB RAM and faced the same performance degradation problem. Issue resolved, and I believe the following solution will work with most of linux distros, and here-under how to regain the full performance/speed of your PC after installing +8GB (10/12/16GB) RAM modules:

1. Install +8GB (10/12/16GB) RAM modules, and wait for the PC to boot up "it will take longer time, usually a few minutes to be able to boot up".
2. After you reach to the desktop you'll notice how slow the PC is, just go to the `/boot/grub/` folder and open the `grub.cfg` file as root or open it using the terminal.
3. Add a <kbd>space</kbd> and then `mem=17G` at the end of every line that starts with `linux /boot/` and `linux16`.
4. Reboot your PC, and congrats, your PC should work normally with the same performance/speed before adding the extra RAM modules.

*You may still face a slow boot up time, and this happens if you resized/formated/created a new swap partition, and in this case you need to replace the old swap partition UUID with the new one in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file, search for `quiet splash resume=UUID=` and replace the old swap partition UUID with the new one for every occurrence.

You should also replace the swap partition UUID in this file `/etc/default/grub` search for the following line and replace the old swap partition UUID with the new one

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=
```

Reboot your PC, and now your PC should work exactly with the full performance/speed before adding the exrta RAM modules.

**Note:**
To get the current UUID of the swap partition, use the `blkid` command in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same notebook model, running Fedora 25, You have to update the grub.cfg file located under /boot/grub2 directory

First open a terminal. Press **ALT + F2** and type **gnome-terminal**. If that doesn't work, type **xterm**, or you can try with **mate-terminal, lxterminal, terminator**, etc. There are a lot of them. If none of these works just run `sudo dnf install xterm` and run the **xterm** terminal using the previous procedure.

After you have your terminal, run these commands, typing them one per line and hitting **ENTER** at the end of each line. Note that you don't have to write anything after the '#' character, that's just a comment mentioning what we are doing at each step

```
$ sudo su -  # It probably will ask your password here, with this command you will become root, or the linux superuser. Note the DNS name for this site haha ;) . Also note that if you don't know what you're doing running commands as root you can hurt your installation. I would recommend doing a backup of your important stuff first.
# cp /boot/grub2/grub.cfg /boot/grub2/grub.cfg.backup.$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S) # this will make a backup of the file in the same directory with current timestamp. If anything goes wrong, you can restore it.
# vim /boot/grub2/grub.cfg # edit the file and locate the lines starting with linux16
```

Run this command inside vim. This will locate the lines which start with the string "linux16". Note that it starts with a slash (/)

```
/^linux16
```

After that go to the end of the line pressing **SHIFT + A** . At this time  vim will switch to "edit" mode, the previous mode was "command" mode. In this "edit" mode enter a space followed by the new parameter `mem=17G`. **Note the space before the parameter**. You will know that you're in "edit" mode if you see the word "-- INSERT --" in the lower left corner of your terminal

Once you've inserted the text, press the **ESC** key to switch back to "command" mode, press the **n** key to look for the next occurrence of the "linux16" string and repeat the previous step

Repeat the searching step and editing step for every occurrence of the "linux16" string

Once you're done with the editing, press **ESC** key and then write `:wq` to save your work and exit vim. You will return to your terminal

Reboot your laptop with the `reboot` command and select the first line, i mean, the latest kernel available. And that should be it.

Particularly for me it didn't make great impact adding this parameter to the kernel command line, but it definitively made some improvement. Please let me know if you succeded and if you could make a bigger improvement.

Regards